# Get multiple streams JSON data from twitch API

Tags: json, twitch

There are two json calls and the call #2 is working. I don't have any idea about the first one (multiple streams).

(I know some of you would say: "go and read the docs right there", but it didn't help me very much. https://github.com/justintv/Twitch-API/blob/master/v2_resources/streams.md)

Call #1:

```
$.getJSON("h ttps://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams?channel=viagamehs,starladder1.json?callback=", function(response){
    response = JSON.stringify(response);
    OBjonline = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
    alert(response);
});
```

Call #2:

```
$.getJSON("h ttps://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/viagamehs_ru.json?callback=?", function(response){
    response = JSON.stringify(response);
    OBjonline = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
    alert(response);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The right code:

```html
        $.getJSON("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams.json?channel=viagamehs,starladder1&callback=?", function(response){
            response = JSON.stringify(response);
            console.log(response);
        });
```